Remove tails and keep median lines using ggridges
I am making a density plot using the R package ggridges. I want to remove the long tails produced by the geom_density_ridges(...) function and keep the vertical median lines produced by the stat_density_ridges(...) function. Is this possible?
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

# Adds median line but has long tails 
diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = cut)) +
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE,
                      quantiles = 2,
                      vline_color = 'red',
                      alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_bw()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0647



# No median line but removes long tails
diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = cut)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.01,
                      alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_bw()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0647



# Adds median line but still has long tails
diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = cut)) +
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE,
                      quantiles = 2,
                      vline_color = 'red',
                      alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.01,
                      alpha = 0) +
  theme_bw()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0647
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0647


Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0

You can combine the parameters, e.g. passing rel_min_height = 0.01 to stat_density_ridges will pass that on the matched geom and will work. See the ... parameter in ?stat_density_ridges
